# how to compare two tables in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

its me with another trouble!

**Table1**

- n: 1
- n: 2
- n: 3

**Table2**

- n: 1
- n: 3

**Query1**

- numeber of results: 3

**Query2**

- numeber of results: 2

I need to compare this tables and if *Table1 == Table2* echo "found". So i made 2 diferent querys and Im doing it like this:

```
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($Query1))
{
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($Query2))
{
if($row1['n'] == $row2['n'] )
{
echo 'found';
}
}
}
```

Kinda dumb? :\ cause it seems show just the 1st result and stop.

Thanks

### EDIT

Exmpl: I got this table: clients, and table: VIP clients. I need to search on table VIP clients if there is any client with same id, and result an echo: "found it"

Comment: You wanna compare table1.firstline to table2.firstline and so on?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about the problem you are trying to solve? It would seem you would know if query1 and query2 were going to produce the same results before you executed them, but thats probably only because I don't quite understand the context which you are using this bit of code.

Comment: sel, yes, all rows. I want to compare if a member of table2 exists on table1

Comment: In that case, y not use inner join to directly query the table? to retrieve all found records.

Comment: Yes, the questions still confusing.  Are you trying to compare if two tables are the same, or if an element of one table is in the other table?  They are very different questions.

Comment: or if an element of one table is in the other table? - THIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you could do it in one query to see if there is any matching records in vipclients.

```
select a.*,b.* ,CASE WHEN b.clientid IS NOT NULL 
       THEN 'FOUND'
       ELSE 'NOT FOUND'
END AS vipexists 
from clients a left outer join vipclients b on a.clientid=b.clientid
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you wanna find if same data exist in both table.
You can store the result into two different arrays

```
$table1 = array();
$table2 = array();
while ($row = mysql_query($result1)){
  $table1[] = $row[0];
}
while ($row = mysql_query($result2)){
  $table2[] = $row[0];
}
```

And then use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to find the intersection of the two

```
$intersect = array_intersect($table1, $table2);
echo count($intersect) > 0 ? "Found" : "Not Found";
```